# How get array in linq to entity?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
var sites = 
    from country in db.Countries
    select new SitiesViewByUser()                
    {         
        Country = country.Title, 
        City = country.Cities
            .Select(m => m.Title).ToArray()                                   
    };
```

City - array string.

I need get array Cities.Title

this code:

```
foreach(var item in sites)
```

get this error:

> Expression of LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   "System.String [] ToArray [String]
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` 1 [System.String]) ", so it
>   can not be converted into an expression store.

Comment: If the type of `City.Title` is `string` then you get exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is. Is the code above not working, and what in that case does it do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to project to an anonymous type, then use `ToArray()` once you are back in Linq to objects land by using `AsEnumerable()`:

```
var sites = 
    (from country in db.Countries
    select new 
    { 
         Country = country.Title,
         Cities = country.Cities.Select(m => m.Title)
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(country => new SitiesViewByUser()
    {         
        Country = country.Title, 
        City = country.Cities.ToArray()
    };
```

The problem is that `ToArray()` is simply not defined for the Linq to Entities `IQueryable` provider (what would be the equivalent call in SQL?). Hence you have to grab your results, switch to Linq to Objects and *then* you can materialize them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToList()` instead. You can make the type of your property `ICollection<T>` which represents a list of items with a known count.

`ToList()` was added for EF 6 in this work item http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/808