# Receive Dictionary<int, string> from linq to entity?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

continuation of the issue [How get array in linq to entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446826/how-get-array-in-linq-to-entity)

but now is not array => Dictionary
City type is Dictionary

```
 var sites = (from country in db.Countries
                        select new
                        {
                            Country = country.Title,
                            Cities = country.Cities.Select(m => m.Title)
                        })
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(country => new SitiesViewByUser()
                        {
                            Country = country.Country,
                            City = country.Cities.ToArray()
                        });
```

update:

```
public class SitiesViewByUser
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<int, string> City { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What's the definition of the City property on SitiesViewByUser?

Comment: Where does the Dictionary's int key come from? Is this the primary key of the city? You aren't retrieving this in your initial LINQ to Entities query.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) to create a dictionary from a LINQ sequence.

The first part is the key, and the second the value, E.g.

```
.Select(country => new SitiesViewByUser()
{
    Country = country.Country,
    City = country.Cities.ToDictionary(c => c, c => c);
});
```

This assumes that `City` on `SitiesViewByUser` is defined as `Dictionary<string, string>`

Your LINQ is quite confusing though. You are creating an anonymous type, asssumed to shape a `Country`, but which has a `Country` property on it, which is infact the `Title` of the country (is that the name of the country?).

You also have a collection of just the city `Titles`, so I'm not sure what value you are going to use in your `City` dictionary on your `SitiesViewByUser` type.

Also, what is a Sitie? :\

**Update**

You could do something like this:

```
var countries = (from country in db.Countries
   select new
   {
     Title = country.Title,
     CityIds = country.Cities.Select(c => c.Id),
     CityTitles = country.Cities.Select(c => c.Title)
   }).AsEnumerable();

// You have a collection of anonymous types at this point, 
// each type representing a country
// You could use a foreach loop to generate a collection 
// of SitiesViewByUser, or you could use LINQ:

var sitiesViewByUsers = countries.Select(c => new SitiesViewByUser
   {
      Country = c.Title,
      City = c.CityIds.Zip(c.CityTitles, (k, v) => new { Key = k, Value = v })
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
   };
```

Alternatively, why don't you change the `SitiesViewByUser` type to be:

```
public class SitiesViewByUser
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do (using fluent syntax):

```
var sitiesViewByUsers = db.Countries.Select(c => new SitiesViewByUser
  {
    Country = c.Title,
    Cities = c.Cities
  });
```